# Angular4 How to know when a ViewChild has been reset

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the template of `main.html` :

```
<button (click)="displayAndUseMyCustomComp()"></button>
<my-custom-comp *ngIf="isMyCustomCompDisplayed" #myCustomComp="myCustomComp"></my-custom-comp>
```

and `main.component.ts` :

```
export class MainComponent {
  constructor() {}
  private isMyCustomCompDisplayed boolean = false
  @ViewChild('myCustomComp') myCustomComp: MyCustomComp

  displayAndUseMyCustomComp() {
     this.isMyCustomCompDisplayed = true
     console.log(this.myCustomComp) // prints undefined 
     setTimeout(() => {
       console.log(this.myCustomComp) // prints {object}
     })
  }

}
```

What's happening is that my template isn't yet refreshed after I set `isMyCustomCompDisplayed`  to `true`. However, if I use a `setTimeout`, `myCustomComp` gets updated and my issue goes away. It is midly hacky, and I was wondering what was the correct way of doing what I am trying to.

Comment: Put the project into something like https://plnkr.co/.

Comment: ie Launch Editor, new select Angular and then . code and save and link back project as link in stack overflow

Comment: You could use <my-custom-comp [style.display]="isVisible() ? : 'block' :none" then have isVisible() toggle internal visible boolean to true in click handler, set initially to false in ngInit. But If you somehow were expecting to manipulate the child from the parent, that's another matter.

Comment: What if you used `@ViewChildren` and subscribed to the changes observable.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### Here is why it's undefined after you call `displayAndUseMyCustomComp`

Angular updates `ViewChild` query list as part of change detection. When Angular was running initial change detection the `isMyCustomCompDisplayed` was `false` and so `myCustomComp` was hidden. The `myCustomComp` was set to `undefined`.

After you make a click the function `displayAndUseMyCustomComp` is executed and `isMyCustomCompDisplayed` is set to `true`. Angular requires a change detection cycle to update the `myCustomComp` query list. However, you try to read the value immediately and so it's still `undefined`. You need to wait for another change detection cycle for Angular to update the query list.

#### Here is why it's working if you wrap the call into `setTimeout`

If you try to read the `myCustomComp` inside the timeout, Angular has a chance to run change detection between the update to `isMyCustomCompDisplayed` and the time you read `myCustomComp`.

#### Here is what happens during that change detection cycle

When Angular runs change detection for the `MainComponent` it detects that `isMyCustomCompDisplayed` is updated. So it goes and updates bindings for `ngIf`. It in turn reacts to this change and creates and embedded view with the `myCustomComp` and attaches it to the `MainComponent` component:

```
  @Input()
  set ngIf(condition: any) {
      if (condidition) {
          this._viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this._thenTemplateRef, this._context);
```

#### When is the updated query list available

If you're looking for synchronous solution, it will be available inside all lifecycle hooks **that are executed after the view children query list** is updated during the next change detection cycle that follows execution of `displayAndUseMyCustomComp`. At the moment these are `ngAfterViewInit` and `ngAfterViewChecked`. Since the former is called only once, we need to use `ngAfterViewChecked`:

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if(this.isMyCustomCompDisplayed) {
        console.log(this.myCustomComp) // prints {object}
    }
  }

  displayAndUseMyCustomComp() {
     this.isMyCustomCompDisplayed = true
  }
```

Another synchronous solution suggested by `@ThinkingMedia` is also good. You can use `ViewChildren` instead of `ViewChild` and subscribe to `changes` (btw you don't template reference):

```
  @ViewChildren(myCustomComp) as: QueryList<myCustomComp>;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myCustomComp.changes.subscribe(() => {
      console.log(this.myCustomComp.first); // prints {object}
    });
  }
```

The callback will be triggered during next digest when Angular will be updating query list (slightly earlier than `ngAfterViewChecked`).

If you're looking for asynchronous solution, use `setTimeout` as you do it. The `Promise.resolve(null).then(()=>{ console.log(this.myCustomComp) })` (microtask) solution won't work because it will be executed after the current stack but before the change detection.

For more information on change detection read
[Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f).

Comment: Do you know if `@ViewChild` triggers `OnChanges` events?

Comment: @ThinkingMedia, do you mean when `@ViewChild` changes will the `OnChanges` be triggered? If so, then no, they are not related. Btw, I've updated the answer to make it more clear what's happening inside.

Comment: " this.myCustomComp.changes.subscribe"
This absolutely SAVED me. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @Reactgular If what you had in mind was, if the element that you want to access by ViewChild is accessible immidiately in OnChanges then the answer is no.